# How to construct a "text/csv" payload when invoking a sagemaker endpoint

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

My training data looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [2, 5], 'B' : [1, 7]})
```

I have trained a model in AWS Sagemaker and I deployed the model behind an endpoint.
The endpoint accepts the payload as "text/csv".

to invoke the endpoint using boto3 you can do:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="my-sagemaker-endpoint-name",
    Body= my_payload_as_csv,
    ContentType = 'text/csv')
```

How do i construct the payload "my_payload_as_csv" from my Dataframe in order to invoke the Sagemaker Endpoint correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you start from the dataframe example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [2, 5], 'B' : [1, 7]})
```

you take a row

```
df_1_record = df[:1]
```

and convert `df_1_record` to a csv like this:

```
import io
from io import StringIO
csv_file = io.StringIO()
# by default sagemaker expects comma seperated
df_1_record.to_csv(csv_file, sep=",", header=False, index=False)
my_payload_as_csv = csv_file.getvalue()
```

`my_payload_as_csv` looks like

```
'2,1\n'
```

then you can invoke the sagemaker endpoint

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="my-sagemaker-endpoint-name",
    Body= my_payload_as_csv,
    ContentType = 'text/csv')
```

Comment: I ran into an error for not using region and so i used: client=boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime',region_name='us-east-1')

Answer (score 2):

@VincentCleas's answer was good. But, If you want to construct csv-payload without installing pandas, do this:

```
import boto3

csv_buffer = open('<file-name>.csv')
my_payload_as_csv = csv_buffer.read()

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="my-sagemaker-endpoint-name",
    Body= my_payload_as_csv,
    ContentType = 'text/csv')
```